# pipe is returning empty string in bash in git for windows

Tags: windows, git, bash, shell, pipe

## Edit: Issue has been resolved after update to Git for Windows >= 2.9.0.windows1

---

#### Disclaimer

Some comments are referring to full "story" behind this issue but I decided to shorten it because it was getting too long and hard to follow. I present you as succinct failing example as possible. For those who are interested in knowing full context of the problem: it is available in [previous revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37643385/11).

---

This: `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")` is the first (excluding hashbang) line in scripts **generated** by npm after installing any package which comes with CLI. 
For some reason `basedir` is incorrectly resolved and that's why node can't find module and crashes. I managed to narrow down problem to the pipe in subshell on latest Git for Windows' git-bash. Executing:

```
echo -n "1:"
echo "a" | cat
echo -n "2:"
echo "$(echo "a" | cat)"
echo -n "3:"
echo "$(echo "a")"
```

prints:

```
1:a
2:
3:a
```

I can't find other people with this issue so I think that it's something wrong with my env (Windows 10 Pro, Git for Windows 2.8.4) and personally I'm out of ideas where it might come from. 
My findings:

- downgrading Git for Windows to 2.6.4 fixes the problem. Still I don't like being stuck on old version ;/
- it works fine on clean Windows 10 VM
- pipe output seems to be completely empty because running following snippet doesn't return any result.
- On clean installation of mingw + msys problem doesn't occur

snippet:

```
echo $(echo foobar | cat > bazzzzzzzzzz ; ) ; cat bazzzzzzzzzz
find /c -name bazzzzzzz* 2> /dev/null # /c, /d and /x are my Windows partitions
find /d -name bazzzzzzz* 2> /dev/null # I did test if it actually works for existing file and it does
find /x -name bazzzzzzz* 2> /dev/null
```

Thanks to agc for invaluable help on figuring this out to this point.

---

My `PATH` variable looks like this:

```
PATH=/c/Users/ja/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/ja/bin:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/program files/graphicsmagick-1.3.23-q16:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/getopt/binaries:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/ja/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Program Files (x86)/MacType:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

also

```
$ which sed
/usr/bin/sed
$ which echo
/usr/bin/echo
$ which cat
/usr/bin/cat
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: Indeed it's not needed in this case, but as I said this script is automatically generated during installation of node package through npm so manually modifying such scripts after every installation almost defeats the idea of using package manager. I also ruled out npm from potential sources of the issue because I can't find anyone struggling with such problem on the internet. Thanks for comment tho :)

Comment: It's acting as though instead of invoking plain `sed` it is invoking `sed -n`, i.e., a version of sed that prints nothing unless explicitly told to print something (or just a completely broken command that always prints nothing).

Comment: Try swapping out `echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g'` with `echo "$0" | tr '\\' '/'`.

Comment: @agc I'd like to avoid having to manually edit generated files. See my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643385/sed-is-returning-empty-string-in-bash-script-in-git-for-windows?noredirect=1#comment-62769763)

Comment: Both errors have something like `$( foo | bar )`, so the next step is to see if you can simplify that.  Does `$( foo )` alone work?  If it does, maybe it's the pipe, so try `$( foo | cat )`.

Comment: @agc I tried without sed and it indeed seems like issue is with pipe. Nice one ;) But how can it's behavior be dependent on my env?

Comment: Ok, so we know that *pipe*s work, simple _command substitution_ works, but a _command substitution_ with a _pipe_ fails -- or perhaps sends the output to some place other than _STDOUT_.  To test that try `echo $(echo foobar | cat > baz ; ) ; cat baz`

Comment: The problem is that for some reason in my env `echo "$(echo "a" | cat)"` is **not** the same as `echo a`. I'm sorry if you felt like being pushed. That was not my intent. You asked to explain the context of this weird looking snippet so I did through that link. IMO it's not crucial to understand the problem and that's why I kindly ask the reader **who is interested in knowing full context** to look there.

Comment: @Sierra I edited question according to your suggestions. Hope that'll suffice.

Comment: What's the PATH look like...? Is there some kind of other `echo`, `cat` that is appearing ahead of (git) bash's version of basic utils? Might be inconsistent set of utilities not playing nicely together.

Comment: @michael_n I added this info to the question but I don't think that `PATH` is might be the cause

Comment: Is there a stack dump after running the command? Could be a bash bug in 2.8.3 (and still in 2.8.4)?   https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2303/  (is this a bug you submitted? note: that bug link won't help much, as it was closed "works-for-me", yet does illustrate the same issue.)

Comment: No stack dump but thank you so much for this link! Now I know im not alone facing this (or very similar) issue :D

Comment: I just installed clean mingw + msys and in msys shell command substitution works as intended so the problem must be somehow related to Git for Windows

Comment: What is your $SHELL variable value?

Comment: @olivecoder It's `/usr/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, the short (tl;dr) version: either downgrade, upgrade, and/or re-install MSYS and MinGW that come with Git for Windows.

[MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) supplements [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW), and the version provided by [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) may be modified from the original maintainers of MSYS. There was [a bug reported against MSYS](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2303/) for what appears to be this same issue (using "mingw version: 64 bit bundled with git version 2.8.3.windows.1"), but was marked as "works for me" (i.e., "can't reproduce"). But there was a comment that the problem could be in the repackaging:

> "Please be advised that MSYS, as bundled with git for windows, may be modified from our official distribution, (and 64-bit MinGW certainly isn't ours); thus we don't formally support either of these." https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2303/

Long story short, looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
> ```

This seems like an example of the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676). Let us break down this line:

> ```
> echo "$0"
> ```

This is usually the path to the script, for example `./alfa.sh`

> ```
> sed -e 's,\\,/,g'
> ```

This replaces backslashes with forward slashes. This is where this line starts
to fall apart:

1. You dont need the `-e`, you can just do `sed 's,\\,/,g'`
2. You probably dont need the `g`, usually just going to be one slash as shown
   above
3. Changing the slashes doesnt really make sense. Bash, even on Windows, is
   going to be using forward slashes already
4. If for some reason the slashes do need to be changed, Sed is not the right
   tool for this anyway, cygpath is:

   ```
   $ cygpath -m 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
   C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe
   ```

> ```
> dirname
> ```

Now you are calling dirname after sed/cygpath. It should be called before, that
way sed/cygpath dont have to replace as much:

```
basedir=$(cygpath -m "$(dirname "$0")")
```

Finally, the sed command is bad for another reason; if you are going to be
spitting out a path, it should be an absolute one, because why not?

```
basedir=$(cygpath -am "$(dirname "$0")")
```

Notice now that no pipe is even involved. I will also add that this problem was
[introduced recently](//github.com/npm/npm/pull/11496) to the NPM repo. You might comment to the devs there.

Comment: Thank you for such verbose answer but as I mentioned before: these scripts are **generated** by npm. What you are proposing is workaround - not using pipe. I simply cannot do this without manually editing each generated script. What I am asking for is hints/clues/ideas of why such scripts are not working **only** on my machine. With help of stackoverflow community I managed to narrow scope of the issue to pipe in the subshell. This is why I don't think it's XY problem.

Also I'm not negating that usage of sed here is at least questionable :)

Comment: While I understand that usage of pipe and sed in these scripts may be inappropriate the fact is that it works as intended for everyone else. I stumbled upon this while trying to execute npm package but it's more generic as it can potentially break every sh script evaluated on my machine and npm has nothing to do with that. If I were to go to the root of the problem I would go to Git for Windows repo but still it does work on clean VM so I don't think that task of guessing potential causes is a right fit for their issue tracker. Asking SO community seems to be a better bet

Comment: @bgoscinski you still have yet to provide a valid example that **needs** a pipe. `cat` is a NOOP in your first example, and the `sed` example can be reworked with `cygpath` ditching the pipe. If you want an answer **give an example that actually requires a pipe**. Just saying "i want this because i want it" is not groovy

Comment: I wan't it because npm's or **any** other similar script will fail on my machine. Isn't it enough for you?

Comment: @Sierra, that a pipe doesn't work is itself more interesting than the code that borders the pipe.  Really it's more of an XY(Z) problem where XY leads to discovering Z, after which XY are both dwarfed by Z.