# How to fix dirname: missing operand

Tags: regex, bash, npm

I have an NPM package that creates time trackers, it uses a `for in` to locate the title of an MD file and then converts it to a tracker. currently when running it on Mac it works fine, on windows I receive `dirname:missing operand`

I tried running on Mac which worked fine, and then back on windows it spits the error. Was googling for solutions but have not found one applicable to my situation

```sh
for file in $(git diff HEAD --name-only | grep -E '\-Day\-LessonPlan\.md$' | xargs -n1 dirname);
do
  ./node_modules/.bin/tt-generator $file;
done
```

I expect it to run and it will access an NPM package and create time trackers for us. Currently on windows I just receive `dirname: missing operand`. Mac works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this error when `dirname` doesn't get any file.

This would mean that the `grep` command doesn't work the same on both machines.

A possible workaround is to let `git` filter the filenames:

```
git diff --name-only "*-Day-LessonPlan.md" | xargs dirname
```

Note also that I remove the `-n1` option of `xargs` since `dirname` can take several filenames.

Comment: When  using that snippet, I'm receiving the same error on windows.

Comment: Yes when the package is complete it will return a .md and .xls file

Comment: @Tammerg Weird... maybe have look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643385/pipe-is-returning-empty-string-in-bash-in-git-for-windows)